# Positioning buttons in a specific way in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, button, layout-manager, boxlayout

I'm trying to position six buttons in a specific way but currently the output is almost right but the buttons are not in the exact positions that I want them to be in (with all buttons touching adjacent buttons with no gaps). This is show below:

[image: button pic]

Could someone have a look at my code to see why the positioning isn't exact?

```
public void createDirectionButtonPanel() {

    JButton northButton = new JButton("north");
    JButton  southButton = new JButton("south");
    JButton westButton = new JButton("west");
    JButton eastButton = new JButton("east");
    JButton upButton = new JButton("up");
    JButton downButton = new JButton("down");

    JPanel directionButtonPanel = new JPanel();
    // directionButtonPanel.setOpaque(false);
    directionButtonPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(directionButtonPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    JPanel directionRow_1 = new JPanel();
    // directionRow_1.setOpaque(false);
    directionRow_1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(directionRow_1, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    directionRow_1.add(Box.createRigidArea(northButton.getPreferredSize()));
    directionRow_1.add(northButton);
    directionRow_1.add(Box.createRigidArea(northButton.getPreferredSize()));
    directionRow_1.add(upButton);

    JPanel directionRow_2 = new JPanel();
    // directionRow_2.setOpaque(false);
    directionRow_2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(directionRow_2, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    directionRow_2.add(westButton);
    directionRow_2.add(Box.createRigidArea(northButton.getPreferredSize()));
    directionRow_2.add(eastButton);
    directionRow_2.add(Box.createRigidArea(northButton.getPreferredSize()));

    JPanel directionRow_3 = new JPanel();
    // directionRow_3.setOpaque(false);
    directionRow_3.setLayout(new BoxLayout(directionRow_3, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    directionRow_3.add(Box.createRigidArea(northButton.getPreferredSize()));
    directionRow_3.add(southButton);
    directionRow_3.add(Box.createRigidArea(northButton.getPreferredSize()));
    directionRow_3.add(downButton);

    upButton.setMaximumSize(southButton.getPreferredSize());
    northButton.setMaximumSize(southButton.getPreferredSize());
    westButton.setMaximumSize(southButton.getPreferredSize());
    southButton.setMaximumSize(southButton.getPreferredSize());
    downButton.setMaximumSize(southButton.getPreferredSize());
    eastButton.setMaximumSize(southButton.getPreferredSize());

    directionButtonPanel.add(directionRow_1);
    directionButtonPanel.add(directionRow_2);
    directionButtonPanel.add(directionRow_3);

}
```

Comment: 1, simpest is by placing 12 JButtuns (rest shouldn't be setVisible(false)), 2. better is search here for joystick or something that looks like as navigations keys (e.g. TVs remote)

Comment: So the image above is what you need?  Or what you have from the code shown?  I'm confused..  The image would be easy to create using `GridLayout`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. GridLayout seems appropriate, as JavaDoc says: **`Creates a grid layout with the specified number of rows and columns. All components in the layout are given equal size.`** Also saves you the trouble of having to arrange the rows yourself. Just add everything to your `directionButtonPanel`.

```
    JButton northButton = new JButton("north");
    JButton southButton = new JButton("south");
    JButton westButton = new JButton("west");
    JButton eastButton = new JButton("east");
    JButton upButton = new JButton("up");
    JButton downButton = new JButton("down");

    JPanel directionButtonPanel = new JPanel();
    directionButtonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,4));

    // row 1
    directionButtonPanel.add(new JPanel());
    directionButtonPanel.add(northButton);
    directionButtonPanel.add(new JPanel());
    directionButtonPanel.add(upButton);

    // row 2
    directionButtonPanel.add(westButton);
    directionButtonPanel.add(new JPanel());
    directionButtonPanel.add(eastButton);
    directionButtonPanel.add(new JPanel());

    // row 3
    directionButtonPanel.add(new JPanel());
    directionButtonPanel.add(southButton);
    directionButtonPanel.add(new JPanel());
    directionButtonPanel.add(downButton);
```